# Text in itemize in column with tikz exeeds margin

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm new to tikz but I don't think the problem is tikz itself. What I want to obtain is simple, a list of file names with an arrow for each element pointing to the middle of and interval of a tikz image.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amsfonts,float,times,subfig,tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\makeatletter
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{-}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Creation Of The Database}

  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.8\linewidth}
      \begin{exampleblock}{}
        \begin{itemize} 
          \item \texttt{RawCh\_NoiseCalib\_Ped.iov.179600\_tnf1\_180474\_Ped.root} $\tikzmark{n1}$
          \item \texttt{RawCh\_NoiseCalib\_Ped.iov.180390\_tnf1\_180474\_Ped.root} $\tikzmark{n2}$
          \item \texttt{RawCh\_NoiseCalib\_Ped.iov.180600\_tnf1\_180474\_Ped.root} $\tikzmark{n3}$
          \item \texttt{RawCh\_NoiseCalib\_Ped.iov.181233\_tnf1\_180474\_Ped.root} $\tikzmark{n4}$
          \item \texttt{RawCh\_NoiseCalib\_Ped.iov.181530\_tnf1\_180474\_Ped.root} $\tikzmark{n5}$
        \end{itemize}
      \end{exampleblock}
    \end{column} \hfill
    \begin{column}{.2\linewidth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- (0,5);

        \node (a) at (0,0) [circle,fill, inner sep = 1.2] {}; 
        \node (b) at (0,1) [circle,fill, inner sep = 1.2] {}; 
        \node (c) at (0,2) [circle,fill, inner sep = 1.2] {}; 
        \node (d) at (0,3) [circle,fill, inner sep = 1.2] {}; 
        \node (e) at (0,4) [circle,fill, inner sep = 1.2] {}; 
        \node (f) at (0,5) [circle,fill, inner sep = 1.2] {};

        \node (t1) at (0,0.5) {};
        \node (t2) at (0,1.5) {};
        \node (t2) at (0,2.5) {};
        \node (t3) at (0,3.5) {};
        \node (t4) at (0,4.5) {};

        \draw (f) node [right] {$181900$}; 
        \draw (e) node [right] {$179600$}; 
        \draw (d) node [right] {$180390$}; 
        \draw (c) node [right] {$180600$}; 
        \draw (b) node [right] {$181233$}; 
        \draw (a) node [right] {$181530$};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}

  \tikz[overlay,remember picture,-latex] \draw[out = 0, in = 0] ($(n1)$) to ($(t1)$);

 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think the `tikzpicture` environment miss the option `remember picture`: this means that the point `t1` isn't know when you are trying to draw the arc.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Thanks for providing a MWE :)  @ClaudioFiandrino yep, that's what I got too :)

Comment: @cmhughes I noticed and you were faster than me of 4s :) What about to improve the answer by shrinking a bit the font size of the file names (I guess `\footnotesize` would suffice)? Upvoting meanwhile.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've added the `[remember picture]` by the way there still are some things I don't understand, why the file names goes on new line? and why they cross the right margin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok guys, thanks to your help I got it working the way I intended, here is the solution

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\makeatletter
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{-}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Creation Of The Database}

  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.8\linewidth}
      \begin{exampleblock}{}
        \begin{itemize}
          \footnotesize{
          \item \texttt{RawCh\_NoiseCalib\_Ped.iov.179600\_tnf1\_180474\_Ped.root} $\tikzmark{n1}$
          \item \texttt{RawCh\_NoiseCalib\_Ped.iov.180390\_tnf1\_180474\_Ped.root} $\tikzmark{n2}$
          \item \texttt{RawCh\_NoiseCalib\_Ped.iov.180600\_tnf1\_180474\_Ped.root} $\tikzmark{n3}$
          \item \texttt{RawCh\_NoiseCalib\_Ped.iov.181233\_tnf1\_180474\_Ped.root} $\tikzmark{n4}$
          \item \texttt{RawCh\_NoiseCalib\_Ped.iov.181530\_tnf1\_180474\_Ped.root} $\tikzmark{n5}$}
        \end{itemize}
      \end{exampleblock}
    \end{column} \hfill
    \begin{column}{.2\linewidth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
        \draw (0,0) -- (0,5);

        \node (a) at (0,0) [circle,fill, inner sep = 1.2] {}; 
        \node (b) at (0,1) [circle,fill, inner sep = 1.2] {}; 
        \node (c) at (0,2) [circle,fill, inner sep = 1.2] {}; 
        \node (d) at (0,3) [circle,fill, inner sep = 1.2] {}; 
        \node (e) at (0,4) [circle,fill, inner sep = 1.2] {}; 
        \node (f) at (0,5) [circle,fill, inner sep = 1.2] {};

        \node (t1) at (0,4.5) {};
        \node (t2) at (0,3.5) {};
        \node (t3) at (0,2.5) {};
        \node (t4) at (0,1.5) {};
        \node (t5) at (0,0.5) {};

        \draw (f) node [right] {$179600$}; 
        \draw (e) node [right] {$180390$}; 
        \draw (d) node [right] {$180600$}; 
        \draw (c) node [right] {$181233$}; 
        \draw (b) node [right] {$181530$};
        \draw (a) node [right] {$181900$};

      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}

  \tikz[overlay,remember picture,-latex] \draw[out = 0, in = 180] ($(n1)$) to ($(t1)$);
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture,-latex] \draw[out = 0, in = 180] ($(n2)$) to ($(t2)$);
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture,-latex] \draw[out = 0, in = 180] ($(n3)$) to ($(t3)$);
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture,-latex] \draw[out = 0, in = 180] ($(n4)$) to ($(t4)$);
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture,-latex] \draw[out = 0, in = 180] ($(n5)$) to ($(t5)$);

 \end{frame}
```

[image: frame]

Answer (score 7):

I think you're missing a `remember picture` from the `tikzpicture` in your second column

[image: screenshot]

I have also removed some of the unnecessary packages from your preamble- a lot of them are loaded by `beamer`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\makeatletter
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{-}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Creation Of The Database}

    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.8\linewidth}
            \begin{exampleblock}{}
                \begin{itemize} 
                    \item \texttt{RawCh\_NoiseCalib\_Ped.iov.179600\_tnf1\_180474\_Ped.root} $\tikzmark{n1}$
                    \item \texttt{RawCh\_NoiseCalib\_Ped.iov.180390\_tnf1\_180474\_Ped.root} $\tikzmark{n2}$
                    \item \texttt{RawCh\_NoiseCalib\_Ped.iov.180600\_tnf1\_180474\_Ped.root} $\tikzmark{n3}$
                    \item \texttt{RawCh\_NoiseCalib\_Ped.iov.181233\_tnf1\_180474\_Ped.root} $\tikzmark{n4}$
                    \item \texttt{RawCh\_NoiseCalib\_Ped.iov.181530\_tnf1\_180474\_Ped.root} $\tikzmark{n5}$
                \end{itemize}
            \end{exampleblock}
        \end{column} \hfill
        \begin{column}{.2\linewidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
                \draw (0,0) -- (0,5);

                \node (a) at (0,0) [circle,fill, inner sep = 1.2] {}; 
                \node (b) at (0,1) [circle,fill, inner sep = 1.2] {}; 
                \node (c) at (0,2) [circle,fill, inner sep = 1.2] {}; 
                \node (d) at (0,3) [circle,fill, inner sep = 1.2] {}; 
                \node (e) at (0,4) [circle,fill, inner sep = 1.2] {}; 
                \node (f) at (0,5) [circle,fill, inner sep = 1.2] {};

                \node (t1) at (0,0.5) {};
                \node (t2) at (0,1.5) {};
                \node (t2) at (0,2.5) {};
                \node (t3) at (0,3.5) {};
                \node (t4) at (0,4.5) {};

                \draw (f) node [right] {$181900$}; 
                \draw (e) node [right] {$179600$}; 
                \draw (d) node [right] {$180390$}; 
                \draw (c) node [right] {$180600$}; 
                \draw (b) node [right] {$181233$}; 
                \draw (a) node [right] {$181530$};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}

    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,-latex] \draw[out = 0, in = 0] ($(n1)$) to ($(t1)$);

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```